# How to create crontab using shell_exec or exec?

Tags: php, cron

Hello I am trying for the first time to use the crontab without using the terminal but only PHP file.
I'm working locally with MAMP on mac.
Am I doing something wrong?

```
<?php
$path= dirname(__FILE__);
shell_exec("crontab -e");
shell_exec("crontab */1 * * * * php ".$path."/run.php");
```

in run.php i would write a text file!
Grazie ciao

Comment: You can redirect the stdout with a `>`, like so: `run.php > somefile.txt`.

Comment: how do i run a file.php?

Comment: Run `php run.php` in terminal.

Comment: The redirection runs for any program, for example `echo "Hello World" > helloWorld.txt`, if you open the newly created helloWorld.txt, you will have the result of the execution. In your case, you just need to append it at the shell_exec.

Comment: I would like to run the file 'run.php' (this file controls deadlines and save)
The file run.php not working!

Answer (score -2):

see here: 
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/
So i think you can just put files in one of that folders with content like "*/1 * * * * php ".$path."/run.php" and that's all.